# Android: How to use extended layout class as ListView row?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating a simple chess clock -type timer app. I'm trying to show the players and the time they have left as rows in a `ListView`. I'm using a custom view that extends `RelativeLayout` for these rows, so that I can give it methods that highlight the player in turn, for example.

**Row layout class:**

```
public class GameTimerView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView nameView;
    private TextView timerView;
    public GameTimerView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_view, this);

        loadViews();
    }

    ...

    private void loadViews() {
        nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        timerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerView);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        nameView.setText(name);
    }

    public void setTime(long timeInMillis) {
        timerView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeInMillis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillis))
        ));
    }

    public void setActive() {
        this.nameView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void setInactive() {
        nameView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

**Row layout XML (timer_view.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timerView"
        android:text="@string/player_default_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/zero_time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class playerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Player> players;

    public playerArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.timer_view, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.players = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GameTimerView playerView = new GameTimerView(context);
        players.get(position).setTimerView(playerView);

        return playerView;
    }
}
```

**Player class setTimerView function:**

```
public void setTimerView(GameTimerView timer) {
    this.timerView = timer;
    this.timerView.setName(this.name);
    this.timerView.setTime(this.totalCountDown);
    this.timerView.setInactive();
}
```

**In the activity's onCreate method:**

```
playerArrayAdapter playersAdapter = new playerArrayAdapter(
        getApplicationContext(),
        game.getPlayers()
);

ListView playersView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playerList);
playersView.setAdapter(playersAdapter);
```

At first this seems to work, and the desired player names and times are rendered to the list properly. However, if I later programmatically call for example `Player.timerView.setActive()`, nothing happens.

Having looked at dozens of examples of custom adapters for ListViews none of them seems to be using it this way - the view is always inflated directly in `Apdater.getView()`. I want the flexibility of an extended view class however, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

So, what's the correct way to use custom view class for `ListView` rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when inflating your `GameTimerView`, you've got a `RelativeLayout`inside another.

Second, to answer the question : it might be good not to re-create a view on each call to `ArrayAdapter.getView()`, but instead modify `playerArrayAdapter` by adding a cache like this :

```
private List<View> views;

public playerArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.timer_view, values);
    views = new ArrayList<View>(values.length);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View playerView;
    if (position < views.size()) {
        playerView = views.get(position);
        if (playerView != null)
            return playerView;
    } else {
        while (views.size() < position)
            views.add(null);
    }
    playerView = new GameTimerView(context);
    views.add(position, playerView);
    players.get(position).setTimerView(playerView);
    return playerView;
}
```

If this successfully corrects your problem, it means that previously, when setting a player as active the `ListView` was getting all views again for rendering, recreating them, and doing so, erasing any previous state.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just to make sure that I understood correctly: So `ArrayAdapter.getView()` is called each time any change (such as changing the text color) happens in the view? And thus this change was just immediately overridden by the creation of a new view?

Comment: It is not said how precisely the function is called. But what's sure is that the function may be called even if a view was already generated for an item at some position. Old views are dropped. To prevent to much garbage collection, the method includes possibility of recycling old views (see `convertView`).

Comment: What was likely happening :
1) Setting the view's color result in the `ListView` becoming invalidated.
2) The `ListView` then iterates over the item using `getView` and then recreating all views. The color set in 1) will then never show.

Answer (score 1):

As per your `getView()` method of `Adapter`, it will create a new view always that might have causing you issue.

If you really want to implement a `CustomViewGroup` then please refer this good implementation of the custom view [here](https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/70524a6b42962be4fbf8). Hope this will help you to start.